# Python Django Session

Tags: django

I'm new with django.

I have this poll app, and I want to limit the voters with 1 vote per session per poll. Example:

poll #1

poll #2

when I will vote to poll #1, after it I can't vote for poll #1 but I can vote for poll #2.

so i decided to place the poll id into a list then check if its in there.

```
poll_list = [] #declare the poll_list variable

@login_required
@never_cache
def vote(request, poll_id):
    global poll_list #declare it as global
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        if poll_id in request.session['has_voted']: #here is the checking happens
            return HttpResponse("You've already voted.")

        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        poll_list.append(poll_id) #i append the poll_id
        request.session['has_voted'] = poll_list #pass to a session
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_results', args=(p.id,)))
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

I got an error:

```
KeyError at /polls/3/vote/
'has_voted'
```

this error will prompt after I click the vote button

anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Unrelated to the question: note that a global `poll_list` won't work very good: if you run multiple django processes in production, each will have its own version of that list. Best to stick polls into the database for instance.

Comment: How can I do that? please help.

Comment: Actually, now that I read your code a little bit better: you don't need the global poll_list. At the start of your method, do a `poll_list = request.session.get('has_voted', [])`. The session is where you want to store it. No need to keep track of it globally when it is really per-session.

Comment: I removed the `global poll_list` but when I press logout then login again. the `poll_list` has the same value. how can i clean the `poll_list` value? The session clears its data when press logout. since I'm using `django.contrib.auth.views.logout`

Comment: Perhaps re-try it with a clean fresh browser session? According to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6941#comment:14 sessions should be cleared, you're right about that. perhaps one of the conditions there applies?

Comment: I think the problems is on the `poll_list` the session is cleared when I logout, but the `poll_list` don't clean is value.

example: 
`poll_list` has already a value of `[u'1',u'2']` then`I press logout. the session `voted_on` is cleared, but what happens to the `poll_list` is `[u'1',u'2',u'1']` it appends the old data and the new data.

so i need to find a way to clean the `poll_list`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10466/discussion-between-justin-and-reinout-van-rees)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't voted yet, `request.session['has_voted']` has not been set yet, so you get a KeyError because the `'has_voted'` key is missing.

You could use `request.session.get('has_voted', [])`, which defaults to an empty list when `has_voted` is missing.

(Note that `has_voted` sounds like a true/false value, `voted_on` might be better).